# Python requests library - Strange behavior vs curl

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I was comparing these two code snippets:

```
subprocess.call('curl -XGET http://localhost:81/proxy/bparc/my_key > /dev/null' ,shell=True)
```

vs

```
response = requests.get('http://localhost:81/proxy/bparc/my_key')
print len(response.text)
```

And the first one will always run in under .01 seconds. But the second one will some times take up to 30 seconds, and other times take less than .01 seconds.

Any ideas what could be going on?  Is requests doing something fancy that's slowing things down?  Is it bad to run len?

Comment: It's not "bad" to run `len`. It's _possible_ that it's relevant—maybe `curl` stops reading data once it sees that you don't want the output, while `requests` can't do that because `len(response.text)` needs the output. But I don't think `curl` actually does that, so…

Comment: Yeah, the requests.get step is instant, so I guess it doesn't download the data until you try to access it?  I'm wondering is asking for response.text is causing it to some processing on the data.  I'm not sure why it's only certain URL's though.

Comment: Right; `requests.get` basically reads only one packet of data (unless it needs more just for the header part of the response); accessing `text` downloads everything. But the only processing it's doing, other than the download, is decoding from bytes to unicode, which should take a tiny fraction of a second.

Comment: If you want to rule out response processing, you can access [`response.content`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) instead, which downloads the raw bytes but doesn't process them. But, again, I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: That was absolutely the issue. Thanks!  Changing to len(response.content) completely fixed it.  I guess only certain data triggered the slowness, maybe related to content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, changing to response.content fixed it.  response.text does a lot of extra stuff you don't need for binary data.

```
response = requests.get('http://localhost:81/proxy/bparc/my_key')
print len(response.content)
```

Comment: Is the response not actually text? In that case, especially if you're on Python 2.6 or 3.0, but maybe also with 2.7 and 3.1+, I could imagine the decoding taking a long time. The old version of the code had to call a function for every single character that failed to decode, and there was no way to short-circuit it.

Comment: Anyway, `r.text` is basically just `r.content.decode(r.encoding)`, which isn't "a lot of extra stuff", it's just one extra thing. Everything else (gzip decoding, etc.) already happens in `content`.

Comment: It's not text, it's binary data.  It's looking like that was the issue.